# How to know if a message is failed to be published by MQTT client to the broker using Eclipse Paho Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, mqtt, iot, paho

I was wondering if there is an alert on Mqtt paho java if a message is failed to be send to MQTT broker in the process of publishing. I'm using MQTT Paho version 3.1.

I have tried the usual way of sending the message to the broker with good connection, but I'm wondering if the Mqtt message s failed to be sent there would be an indication or something so that it could be send later on

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74570256/edit) the question to show the code you are using (so we can see if you are using sync or async and what QOS you are publishing with)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.